# Malformed mfa_token message when trying to challenge an user with MFA

Tags: auth0, multi-factor-authentication, okta-api, auth0-connection

I am developing an iPhone application to demonstrate the MFA using sms factor with MFA APIs for POC. I am using the authorisation flow for getting my access token (where I get a authorisation code and redeem it for an access token)earlier to MFA implementation. From the documentation, I found out that I need an `MFA_token` to work with MFA APIs. I added few changes with my existing authorisation process.

I am getting an MFA Token by doing the following steps:

1. Added scope enroll read:authenticators to authorisation endpoint( i.e. `“https://<my_domain>/authorize”`)
2. Added an audience:
   `https://<my_domain>/mfa` to the authorisation endpoint
3. Then I make a post request to token endpoint with authorization code to get the    `mfa_token`.
4. The only changes I can observe is now the access token(which I presume to be the `mfa_token`) is in jwt format with expire time 600 sec. By using this access token(=mfa_token)
5. I built a custom pages for my user for enrollment and challenging the user via sms.
6. I am able to enroll user, confirm enrollment using this access token.
7. But when I challenge an user using this access token I get the following error after `https://YOUR_DOMAIN/mfa/challenge` call.

```json
{
“error”: “invalid_grant”,
“error_description”: “Malformed mfa_token”
}
```

Can anyone please say me where I am going wrong?

Is the access token same as the MFA_Token in my case?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the `access_token` only serves as `mfa_token` during OOB/device registration.  Thenafter, the user will get an `mfa_token` during auth, which is passed for MFA/OTP challenges

- https://auth0.com/docs/login/mfa/ropg-mfa/manage-authenticator-factors-mfa-api#resource-owner-password-grant

Comment: Thanks for replying and apologies for replying to your comment lately.
No, `access_token` & `mfa_token` are two different thing here. I tried with the same strategy it didn't worked. We can get the mfa_token by using Resource Owner Password Flow only. I was able to get it in the response. Earlier I was trying with authorisation code flow and was not able to get. 
Please refer: https://auth0.com/docs/secure/multi-factor-authentication/authenticate-using-ropg-flow-with-mfa